# What is the minimum PWM frequency that LT1999-10 can capture with smooth output settling?

Tags: pwm, current-measurement, high-voltage

I am referring data sheet of [LT1999-10](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1999-10-1999-20-1999-50.pdf),

My PWM signal is 100Hz duty 5% resolution 8 bit

I have a doubt,

Data sheet - 2MHz bandwidth

**Is this IC able to capture 100Hz PWM signal? will output of IC settle as shown in below figure. or goto 0V before seeing next pulse when 100Hz PWM m is applied?**

*figure shows high frequency PWM with smooth output* - a good settling which is i am expecting for 100Hz.

[image]

Comment: The datasheet implies this is easily in range. What confuses you?

Comment: @Sparky256 will output settle without degrading to 0V?, since plot look like degrading in output voltage until next pulse appear. will it got to 0V before next pulse appear when pwm is 100Hz?

Comment: @kobi89 it's working exactly as expected in terms of rise-decay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot of \$V_{OUT}\$ in your question is, in effect, the plot of motor current when driven with a square wave voltage of 100 kHz and is therefore triangular in nature. This is because the motor is basically an inductive device and if you apply a high-speed square wave voltage to an inductor, you get a triangle wave of current.

> *since plot look like degrading in output voltage until next pulse
> appear. will it got to 0V before next pulse appear when pwm is 100Hz?*

No, you are mistaking normal current waveforms for some degradation in the processing of that signal. This won't happen. Just look at the circuit inside the red box: -

[image]

Clearly, the LT1999 is monitoring current in the motor and the waveforms show no degradation.

Comment: if i set my gain to get 2.5V at Vout for maximum I_sense so it wont go to 0V while pwm is applied to the load at 100Hz between two cycles? how to ensure this?

Comment: \$V_{REF}\$ sets the neutral point on the output. This is 2.5 volts if the LT1999 is powered from 5 volts so, when current ramps up in one direction, \$V_{OUT}\$ rises above 2.5 volts and, when the bridge reverses, the current will ramp down and cause \$V_{OUT}\$ to drop below 2.5 volts. 2.5 volts is the natural quiescent operating point on the output. Additionally \$V_{OUT}\$ can not swing down to a voltage lower than about typically +100 mV above 0 volts - see page 7 of the [revE data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1999-10-1999-20-1999-50.pdf).

Comment: if load is a LED will Vout swing in same way?

Comment: What load? Where is it?

Comment: if the motor inside the red box of the circuit is replaced with an LED

Comment: I think you need to show your circuit because this idea sounds like you might put the LED in a situation where the reverse voltage causes it to fail. If you are trying to drive (say) a laser LED and monitor the current then there are better circuits than the LT1999 and you certainly wouldn't use a H bridge. So, you need to show your circuit. Add it to your question but add it so that it is clearly seen as an addition or it might make my answer look incompetent.

Comment: i do not need h ridge here, LED will be simply connected on the power path series with the Rsense.

Comment: How are you activating the LED at 100 Hz? What is this circuit looking like?

Comment: via an mosfet switch drain is at 100V , gate 100Hz pwm signal from micro controller, i was thinking to use this IC's Rsense series with the led high side.

Comment: The input can only handle up to +80 volts. I really think you need to show a proposal schematic. I don't want to keep second guessing what you might be considering. Is there any reason you can't put Rsense lower down the string of LEDs.